# Hiding graphics created by 'Graphics'

Tags: c#

I have not studied much of the Graphics class in C# but have found myself needing it for my day to day fun times (coding to pass time).

I would just like to know if there is a way to store the graphics drawn (before they are visibly seen on a form) so that I may have the whole segment drawn at the same time instead of having it drawn one by one. By segment I mean a collection of the shapes that are draw-able using the `Graphics` class.

In other words I am trying to get all of this drawn before I attempt to show it on the screen by calling `.FillRectangle`, or equivalent.

Also is there any known way to draw graphics without using the existing methods like GDI+ etc?

If I have missed anything let me know.

EDIT CODE:

```
      using (Graphics formGraphics = df.CreateGraphics())
        {
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            foreach (Dot d in memmap)
            {
                c = Color.FromArgb(d.r, d.g, d.b);
                using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(c))
                {
                    formGraphics.FillRectangle(brush, d.x, d.y, 1, 1);
                }
            }
            this.DoubleBuffered = false;
        }
```

Comment: Wouldn't simply drawing to a Graphics from an Image (that isn't shown) will do the trick? After calling all the drawing methods you can set the Graphics to some form/image to show it.

Comment: This is true and I thought about doing so, but that would mean it has to draw it in the first place, and I can make a form for that, that is hidden and for gods sake that would fix it would it?... I tend to do that sorry I will go try that now!

Comment: Odd, simply creating a blank Image without any Form holding it should be possible (as in, a var blah = new Bitmap(blahblah) instead of creating it from the toolbox)

Answer (score 0):

What you were doing should work if you leave the DoubleBuffered property true all the time and let the framework handle it. Did you try that? Anyway, I prefer to have more control and create the double buffer on my code:

```
using
(
    var bufferedGraphics = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current.Allocate(formGraphics, 
      new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
)
{
    //Draw with bufferendGraphics.Graphics
    bufferedGraphics.Render();
}
```

The above code could be optimized a bit more if you keep the `formGraphics` and the `bufferendGraphics` alive during execution... but that introduces a leak, you need to make sure to dispose them before the from is closed.

By the way, why are you using CreateGraphics? I would override OnPaint of the form and take the graphics from the PaintEventArgs.